# Quarkus deployment erro on Heroku: Could not find or load main class $JAVA_OPTS

Tags: java, maven, heroku, quarkus

i'm trying to deploy a quarkus restful api to Heroku but I'm getting a error and I can't find solutions for it on stackoverflow, quarkus doc or heroku guides.

Running `heroku local web` or getting the logs from the server I got the same error, witch is

> 2021-07-09T04:34:33.763801+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Could not find or load main class $JAVA_OPTS
> 2021-07-09T04:34:33.763822+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: $JAVA_OPTS

In some research I find that this problem maybe related to **Procfile** and this is what's in there

> web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/quarkus-app/quarkus-run.jar

Does anyone can help me out? or show me the way to solve this

Thanks!

Just in case someone ask, here is my pom.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>   <groupId>br.com.uff.dac</groupId> <artifactId>dac-api</artifactId>   <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>   <properties>
    <compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.parameters>true</maven.compiler.parameters>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-universe-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
    <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus</quarkus.platform.group-id>
    <quarkus.platform.version>2.0.1.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
    <surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M5</surefire-plugin.version>   </properties>   <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>   </dependencyManagement>   <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jsonb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-container-image-docker</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>   </dependencies>   <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>build</goal>
              <goal>generate-code</goal>
              <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <parameters>${maven.compiler.parameters}</parameters>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
            <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>   </build>   <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>native</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>native</name>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <goals>
                  <goal>integration-test</goal>
                  <goal>verify</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <native.image.path>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner</native.image.path>
                    <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                    <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                  </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
      <properties>
        <quarkus.package.type>native</quarkus.package.type>
      </properties>
    </profile>   </profiles> </project>
```

Comment: just remove the $java_opts

Comment: doesn't work @karelss

Comment: I sill think that this is a clear issue with the command line and its nor related to quarkus at all, but i will try to reproduce it.

Comment: It ended up working with the java_opts too

Answer (score 2):

I ended up descovering that the right commando in Procfile is this

> web: java -Dquarkus.http.port=$PORT $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/quarkus-app/quarkus-run.jar