# heroku local web returns java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: \\$JAVA_OPTS for quarkus app

Tags: java, deployment, quarkus, heroku-cli, java-opts

I did following tutorial using maven: [deploying-to-heroku](https://quarkus.io/guides/deploying-to-heroku), but the local deployment fails (tried on Windows 11 and WSL2):

```bash
heroku local web
21:55:27 web.1   |  Fehler: Hauptklasse \\$JAVA_OPTS konnte nicht gefunden oder geladen werden
21:55:27 web.1   |  Ursache: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: \\$JAVA_OPTS
[DONE] Killing all processes with signal  SIGINT
21:55:27 web.1   Exited with exit code null
```

Procfile:
`web: java \$JAVA_OPTS -jar target/quarkus-app/quarkus-run.jar`

system.properties:
`java.runtime.version=17`

application.properties:
...
`quarkus.http.port=${PORT:8080}`

pom.xml:

```xml
...
<compiler-plugin.version>3.11.0</compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
...
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. The app works fine in dev mode and all of my tests pass.

I tried `web: java -Dquarkus.http.port=$PORT $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/quarkus-app/quarkus-run.jar` from [Quarkus deployment erro on Heroku: Could not find or load main class $JAVA_OPTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68311642/quarkus-deployment-erro-on-heroku-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-java-opts) too, but it returned the same error.
And I tried `web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/quarkus-app/quarkus-run.jar` from the tutorial. Same result.

Github Repo: https://github.com/jonasfroeller/rate-it

Answer (score 0):

The guide you linked to says

```bash
echo "web: java \$JAVA_OPTS -jar target/quarkus-app/quarkus-run.jar" >> Procfile
```

which will result in

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/quarkus-app/quarkus-run.jar
```

written to `Procfile`.

But you have put

```
web: java \$JAVA_OPTS -jar target/quarkus-app/quarkus-run.jar
```

to `Procfile` which then causes `$JAVA_OPTS` to not be replaced by the value of the environment variable but given literally to `java` which then understands this as the main class it should start and complains that it does not find it.

If you remove the erroneous backslash, I'd expect it to work, given the guide you use is correct and up-to-date, and you did not do further errors while following it.

Comment: I tried that before writing `web: java \$JAVA_OPTS -jar target/quarkus-app/quarkus-run.jar`. Same result.

Comment: Just looked at my current config. It is `web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/quarkus-app/quarkus-run.jar`. Doesn't work.

Comment: If that's the case, I recommend contacting Heroku support, because even their own guides, for example at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-webapp-runner or https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-support suggest that `JAVA_HOME` should be set and recommend having it like that in the `Procfile`.